# Mixed orientations in wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Currently I am using `wicked_pdf` gem to create pdf in my ROR (ruby on rails application).

My pdf have 4 pages. In which 1 is chart. I need that page alone to be landscape dynamically.

Is it possible using `wicked_pdf` or any other gem?

> PS: I tried to generated each pdf and combining them but the image
>   changes pages based on the content of the previous pages.

Answer (score 1):

`wicked_pdf` is a plugin that relies on the `wkhtmltopdf` project to generate the actual PDFs. `wkhtmltopdf` does not yet implement this feature, so until that is complete there is no easy way to get mixed-orientation PDF files.

There is an outstanding [feature request](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1564) to implement this, so watch that issue for any updates. It appears that at this time there is some work being done on this issue but it will take time for it to both make it into `wkhtmltopdf` and be picked up by `wicked_pdf`.

In the meantime there is a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983785/mixing-page-orientations-in-wkhtmltopdf) that some people have attempted involving CSS rotations and media selection stylesheets.

Others have attempted to generate multiple PDFs separately and stitch them together with some programs like `ghostscript`. See the above workaround page for more details.

Comment: As noted above, this is not possible with wkhtmltopdf, but the commercial library https://princexml.com or their hosted partner https://docraptor.com support this behavior. Unfortunately, not of the browsers (and browser-based libraries) fully support CSS3 Paged Media.