# set second page orientation to landscape

Tags: odoo-8, qweb

I want to set the second page orientation to landscape, for that I used css `transform` property, but  I have some issues (the content should fit the page).

I want to know if it is possible using QWEB?

Comment: This might help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983785/mixing-page-orientations-in-wkhtmltopdf