# How to set particular page in landscape using Rotativa MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, rotativa

I have created a MVC 5 project. In this project, I have designed some partial view.
Using Rotativa.MVC, I can convert partial view to pdf.

I want to set landscape page for pdf.

How to set a single page in landscape when partial view convert to pdf using Rotativa.MVC?

I have used below code for convert partial view to pdf.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult TestAction(TestViewModel testViewModel)
    {
        return PartialView("_testPartial", testViewModel);
    }
```

Please suggest me solution for above functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
public ActionResult DownloadViewPDF(List<GetPolice_Result> model)
{
    return new Rotativa.ViewAsPdf("ViewRapor", model)
    {
        PageOrientation = Rotativa.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
        FileName = "EfegulViewAsPdf.pdf"
    };
}
```

Comment: This solution seeems to only apply to entire PDF, so it's not exactly what is asked in the question, as the user whants to know hot to change orientation to a particular single page inside the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

please use below code,

```
 public ActionResult TestAction(TestViewModel testViewModel)
 {
    return new Rotativa.MVC.ViewAsPdf("_testPartial", testViewModel)
            {
                RotativaOptions = new Rotativa.Core.DriverOptions()
                {
                    PageOrientation = Rotativa.Core.Options.Orientation.Landscape,
                },
            };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's is no built-in solution provided by Rotativa to asign different orientation for a single page within the generated PDF. The best way should be using *CustomSwitches* for ***WkHtmlToPdf*** (used by Rotativa to generate the PDF), but there's is an open request since long ago, and you can see, still no definitive solution:

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1564

https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/pull/4439

We've tried once, using CSS (`size` attribute and partial views), with no luck, but there is an existing workaround using CSS `transform`:

[Mixing page orientations in wkhtmltopdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983785/mixing-page-orientations-in-wkhtmltopdf)

On this post answer another possible workaround is mentioned: using 2 different PDF files and merging them usign Ghostscript.

At this time, it seems that these alternatives are the only way to make this possible, or wait for ***WkHtmlToPdf*** command solution.